# Why Route in an array to open two components at the same time

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is my code

```
import React, { Fragment } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Link, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

const Home = () => <div>Home</div>;
const About = () => <div>About</div>;
const NoMatch = () => <div>NoMatch</div>;

const RouteAbout = (
  <Route key={"1"} path={"/About/Photo/Public/:Fuu"} component={About} />
);
const RouteNoMatch = (
  <Route key={"2"} path={"/About/Photo/:Juu"} component={NoMatch} />
);
const RouteAboutNoMatch = [RouteAbout, RouteNoMatch];

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <div>
          <Link to="/">Home</Link>
          <Link to="/About/Photo/Public/Fuu">About</Link>
          <Link to="/About/Photo/Juu">NoMatch</Link>

          <Switch>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Fragment>{RouteAboutNoMatch}</Fragment>
            <Route component={NoMatch} />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

when I click on link About.About and NoMatch both components open.But I expect to see the About component on the screen.What is the problem how to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<Switch>` returns only one first matching route.

`exact` returns any number of routes that match exactly.

When your routes are like this,

```
<Route key={"1"} path={"/About/Photo/Public/:Fuu"} component={About} />
<Route key={"2"} path={"/About/Photo/:Juu"} component={NoMatch} />
```

Interpretation for better understanding

```
<Route key={"1"} path={"/base_path/sub_path_1/sub_path_2/sub_path_3"} component={About} />
<Route key={"2"} path={"/base_path/sub_path_1/sub_path_2"} component={NoMatch} />
```

Now when you clicked on the `About` link, then it searches for route and in this case it is end up with two routes with path `/base_path/sub_path_1/sub_path_2` and you are getting `About` and `NoMatch` component at a time.

so you need to specify **`exact` attribute** to get only one component.

**Also there is a point where to add `exact`, so whichever route has less `sub_path` for that route you need to add `exact` attribute.**

In your case you should add `exact` attribute to `NoMatch` component route because it has less `sub_path`.

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-codesandbox-p1c9q?fontsize=14)

Answer (score 1):

you have to specify exact in your route

```
const RouteAbout = (
  <Route key={"1"} exact path={"/About/Photo/Public/:Fuu"} component={About} />
);
const RouteNoMatch = (
  <Route key={"2"} exact  path={"/About/Photo/:Juu"} component={NoMatch} />
);
```

Comment: But for this there is a switch.

Comment: try to used exact in that because your in array and it is confusing for that so it is showing you both components